Single-threaded async-friendly RefCell that releases borrows while waiting?
The description in Async-friendly RefCell that prevents borrow across await points was a misstatement of the problem.
I want to have something like:
struct Foo {
   inner: SingleThreadedAsyncCell<Inner>
}

impl Foo {
   pub async fn do_something(&self) {
       self.inner.borrow().really_do_something().await;
   }

   pub async fn do_something_else(&self) {
       self.inner.borrow_mut().really_do_something_else().await;
   }
}

async fn do_many_somethings(f: &Foo) {
   join!(f.do_something(), f.do_something_else(), f.do_something_else());
}

It should be safe to concurrently borrow and borrow_mut even while waiting since the interior is written to handle concurrent mut while suspended.
I want to make sure that the borrow is held while polling but released while waiting. That being said, I'm not tied to this specific RefCell-like API. If there's an alternate way of framing a solution I'm open to hearing ideas.
Or in this case do I just fall back to storing all the mutable state behind an UnsafeCell?

Can you change do_something() and do_something_else()?

No. Think of do_something as "read from a file" and do_something_else as "write to a file" except the write path also needs to mutate state internally.

Oh maybe I misunderstood the question. Thought you were asking if I can change do_something to be do_something_else. If you're asking if I can change the interior implementation, yes within reason. Ideally whatever the solution pattern looks like it's something I can copy-paste into similar contexts throughout the codebase.

Then the best (and perhaps the only) way is to change them to take the RefCell instead and only borrow between await points.

That doesn't work because that presumes that the interior of the RefCell always has synchronous functions which isn't the case here.

"It should be safe to concurrently borrow and borrow_mut even while waiting since the interior is written to handle concurrent mut while suspended" - I'm not sure I understand. If the Inner type is crafted such that mutation can be allowed while outstanding immutable references exist then it must handle that "interior mutability" itself and thus doesn't need .borrow_mut(). Unless you are asking if some SingleThreadedAsyncCell exists that can allow that transparently, cuz then the answer is probably no.

Sounds like you want an async mutex (or async rwlock)?

Putting it another way, if really_do_something takes an immutable reference to Inner and really_do_something_else takes a mutable reference to the same Inner, then they cannot run concurrently even while one is suspended. That would be a violation of Rust's rules. You can defer following the rules until runtime with an interior mutability type (like refcell, mutex, etc), but the rules must still be followed which means that a &mut must be exclusive while it is used (which will means some locking behavior).

If you can't change them too, you're out of luck. You cannot do what you want (in a UB-free way).

@kmdreko I don't see how it's a violation. They're running interleaved on the same thread. If you wrapped it behind a RefCell that was acquired during polling it would be fine. AsyncMutex is the wrong model (it's for thread concurrency protection) & doesn't actually help (i.e. holding the async mutex across await points enforces mutual exclusion between readers & writers whereas the data structures involved are safe for multiple simultaneous readers / writers since it's a single thread)

It is a violation for the same reason that immutable/mutable reference interleaving is disallowed in a trivial non-async example. Playground. To be as precise as I can: if an async task holds a mutable reference across an .await and thus suspends, that same reference may not be accessed by another task in the meantime. If you can avoid that by "releasing" the mutable borrow before and re-acquiring it after the .await, then Chayim's suggestion to "take the RefCell instead ...

... and only borrow between await points" would be sufficient and possible. However, you've said that you need to .await while the interior is held, which means what you want is not possible.

Aside from the fact that the lifetimes of this snippet prevent you from actually doing the thing, what would be unsound or a violation about something like this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=941c9283f2dac4810dc9e4f16913b320
Yes it uses unsafe to get a reference to hand to async, but all usage is protected by borrow / borrow_mut. It's not a working example & there's bugs, but I'm trying to highlight a theoretical direction on how it could maybe work.

@Vitali mapping my problematic case above using your proposed wrapper yields undefined behavior. Yes it compiles and "runs", but Miri catches it: playground link. Just follow the execution yourself to see what can go wrong (e.g. in the code I show, tries to read from a dangling reference if allowed).

What you're asking is fundamentally unsound.  Here is a counter-example proving why:
struct Foo {
    inner: SingleThreadedAsyncCell<Vec<String>>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub async fn do_something(&self) {
        let inner = self.inner.borrow();
        let item = inner.get(0).unwrap();
        something().await;
        println!("{item}");
    }

    pub async fn do_something_else(&self) {
        self.inner.borrow_mut().clear();
    }
}

async fn do_many_somethings(f: &Foo) {
    join!(f.do_something(), f.do_something_else(), f.do_something_else());
}

The future returned by do_something is referencing an item from the Vec, but do_something_else clears the Vec, which means do_something can (depending on the order the futures are executed) wind up holding a reference to an invalid value.  This is a classic use-after-free, and is one such example of why references cannot be disregarded just because the thread/task/future holding them is not currently running.
It's a common misconception that Rust's borrowing model is only for multithreaded code.  This is not true at all.  There are plenty of data races that can manifest in a single-threaded environment, especially when using coroutines (which is essentially what futures are).

I think there's only unsoundness if you were allowed to access a reference across an await point. But if the await point forced inner to be reborrowed before returning, you'd be prohibited from the example you provided. Think of it this way - if you returned an explicit Future impl that took &RefCell and prevented you from holding an explicit borrow across an await point, it would be sound. But doing so is viral because you can't hold unnamed futures unless you box them (i.e. chaining async is a problem with explicit futures). So I'm asking if there's a way to accomplish something more elegant

Here's an example of something I'm thinking of: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=941c9283f2dac4810dc9e4f16913b320
This isn't actually the sound version of the API - you'd have to make sure that the argument you pass in can't hold a borrow across await rather than passing in &T (or similarly have it return BorrowedFuture), but it's just meant to be a motivating example.

@Vitali I'm a bit confused because if you can't hold a borrow across an await point then why not just use RefCell and don't hold a guard across an await point? Fundamentally, though, I don't think there's any mechanism in Rust that could do this regardless of whether an interior reference is even held, because there's no language-level support for injecting code before or after an await point (unless you count macros).

@Vitali On second glance I think I see what you're getting at. To make this clean I think you'd need a "special kind of future" whose poll method takes the reference acquired from the RefCell, which would ensure that the reference cannot exist across an await point -- an "await point" is just when the poll method returns Poll::Pending, at which point it can't be holding the reference anymore. I can't think of a great way to integrate that with e.g. async blocks, though.
